# How to add border to a text only and align center

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

I am new to Html & CSS. I want a heading which contains text like "Women safty". I want to warp the heading text with border. But when I apply border to text the border covers all the area in the width both left and right.I just want to add border **around text only** and the text needs to be in **center**.[image][image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a span

HTML

```
<span>Women safty</span>
```

CSS

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    border: solid;
}
```

Result

[image]

Using a div, h1 and p

HTML

```
<h1>Women safty</h1><br /><br />
<div>Women safty</div><br /><br />
<p>Women safty</p><br /><br />
```

CSS

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    border: solid;
    display: inline;
}
div {
    border: solid;
    display: inline;
}
p {
    border: solid;
    display: inline;
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Tnx bro it worked. Both the method worked. Can I able to use <h1> tag after span tag .Tnx a lot @cerebrus6

Comment: Yes you can. Also, a thing to take note. Even if span, div, p and h1 have almost the same effect in word wrapping the text, if you want to adjust the width manually, you cannot do it if you use span. But if you use div, p and h1, you can adjust them easily using width and height in css. Have a wonderful programming journey @NaVeEdIbRaHiM.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your text in HTML:

```
 <p>Women Safety</p>
```

In your CSS create your border with this command:

```
p.solid {border-style: solid; display:inline}
```

Comment: If I use this line the whole html page is covered with border .i.e to the left and right. But I only want the border around the text

Comment: I edited my answer. Use display: inline to have just around the text. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="border: 1px solid red;display: inline-block;">Women safty</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```css
#test {
  border: solid; padding: 0.5%; display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p id="test">Women Safety</p>
```